# Detect outliers of a single 2D cluster (no normal distribution)

Tags: statistics

Imagine I have a single cluster of points in a 2D map (not in a normal distribution), each point having (x,y) coordinates. Thus, no need to do data categorization.

[image]

What's the simplest technique to remove outliers from this 2D cluster?

I need to write out of the box a JavaScript function, since I couldn't find anything for JavaScript. Thus I want something simple to implement.

### What did I imagine

I imagined to have 3 arrays: array of all $x$ coordinates, array of all $y$ coordinates and an array of the distances $d$ of each point to the center of the cluster, i.e., $d=\sqrt{(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2}$ where the center is $c=(c_x,c_y)$.

Then I would apply a simple 1D outlier algorithm to each of the 3 arrays and remove all the corresponding points if any respective coordinate (x, y, d) would be an outlier.

Is this reasonable?

Comment: Do you expect the cluster to be rotationally symmetric?

Comment: @user619894 no, it can have any shape, as long as it forms somehow a conglomerate of points

Comment: then distance to the center is not good enough

Comment: @user619894 that's why I would also consider x and y coordinates

Comment: Probably has the same problem. I suggest you run a density based clustering algorithm, e.g. DBSCAN on the data, and consider the largest cluster as the inliers.

Comment: @user619894 since I did not find anything ready to use I created one https://www.npmjs.com/package/outliers2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering I did not find anything ready to be used out of the box, I created myself a npm package named [outliers2d](https://www.npmjs.com/package/outliers2d).